# Named Pipes Provider error 40 connecting to localhost SQL Server (not a common resolution)

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to create the reporting services database for usage in SCCM. The reporting services installed fine (install only), but once I get to the Database tab and try to connect to the database server to create the database, it fails by timing out when trying to connect (see dialog). I am using Authentication Type: Current User - Integrated Security (domain user account loaded with permissions on that server - used by several other SQL apps).

Full text of error message:
*Could not connect to server: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes provider, error: 50 - Could not open a connection to the SQL Server)*

[image: Named Pipes Provider error 40]

We are using two named instances, so the ports are dynamic. I have made sure all ports are active (netstat).

I also made sure of the following:

- All SQL services are running and have been restarted several times
- Firewall is disabled (all profiles) - shouldn't matter, because we are running setup locally
- Remote connections are enabled in SSMS (again, shouldn't matter)
- Named pipes is enabled (as are TCP/IP and Shared Memory); also re-ordered protocols while testing
- Tried service accounts using virtual service account, local system, network service and known-good domain SQL service account
- Varied Server Name by using machine name, FQDN, local IP, loopback (127.0.0.1) and LOCALHOST
- I can ping the server and access IPC$ (as you would expect on the localhost)
- I am inside of the SQL Server 2016 Reporting Services Configuration Manager and logged into the SQL Server on the correct instance and the Report Server is showing as Started. I can also user the Web Service URL (although it obviously gives me a DB error).

I have checked the Application Event log and SQL/Reporting Server logs without any hints of the problem.

What could be causing this issue? I have spent hours troubleshooting something that should be so easy.

Comment: Have you enabled SQL Browser

Comment: To elaborate on Charlieface's comment, when using instance names the SQL Browser service must be running and accessible via udp/1434. When instance names are in the connection string SQL Clients connect to the Browser service first, to resolve the instance name to a tcp port, then establish a tcp connection to the resolved port.

Comment: Yes, SQL Server Browser is running, and port 1434/UDP is active (checked with netstat).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize that the Server name field when creating the database still requires the instance name even though the installation already had that embedded.  It was just a matter of clicking that field and accepting the server\instance dropdown.  I had the biggest face palm in a very long time.